# Setting all bits in range [m,n] to 1

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, uint

Im using the code in [This Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-bits-set-given-range/) to generate a `uint` whose bit are all set to 1 in a desired range of indeces.

eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    // range is [32,5] so i want [1 1 1......1 0 0 0 0 0]
    uint mask = ((1 << 32) - 1) ^ ((1 << (5 - 1)) - 1);
    std::cout << mask << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `4294967280`, which contains the desired array of bits according to [this site](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_unsigned_int.html).

But as soon as i do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () 
{
    uint stop = 32;
    uint start = 5;
    uint mask = ((1 << stop) - 1) ^ ((1 << (start - 1)) - 1);
    std::cout << mask << std::endl; 
}
```

It outputs `15`. Uuuuh what's is going on? are the `32` and `5` in the first example a different type that gets casted when assigning to the `uint mask`? how do i fix this?

Comment: Overflow? You only have 32 bits

Comment: This depends on the size of your `uint` (which isn't a c++ type, I'll assume you meant `unsigned int`). If it's 32 bit, then `1<<32` is an overflow.

Comment: why do you subtract 1 in case of 5 but not in case of 32?

Comment: if you dont subtract by 1 the last (from left to right) of the bits you want 1 is actually 0